# Groovy Pipeline Getting last n commits and changes from git

Tags: git, powershell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a git repository that has files dropped and removed.  Each file is unique and has a link inside of it.  We use Jenkins to poll git and get that commit, then launch a Jenkins build off of it.
Problem I am facing now is, I want to get the last n number of those commits from master, and iterate through each commit to determine which of those should be rebuilt based on some criteria.

Is it possible to get that information from git via groovy?  I am finding that the last commit, last jenkins build is possible, but I need more.  Is there a way to do this other than writing a Powershell script that returns such data?

Windows env. Thanks in advance, hope this was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. You can get [all changes in the current build](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job-) and you can navigate
   to previous builds: [currentBuild.previousBuild.changeSets](https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild).

   Hint: Check if there's a previous Build:
   `if(currentBuild.previousBuild)` or use null safe operator: `currentBuild.previousBuild?.changeSets`
2. You can write a [Shared Library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), which serves your specific needs. This takes more effort and is more error prone/difficult, since Jenkins uses CPS (Continuous Passing Style) for Groovy Scripts. You're able to use libraries from the Maven Repository within Groovy Scripts using [Grape](http://www.groovy-lang.org/grape.html).

Comment: I had to go further back in history, and in the end, it was easier to write a powershell that just called git log, massage the data and then return that back to groovy.  Thanks for the assist, still very useful.